SPFX react control in cdn library
I am using @pnp/spfx-controls-react version 3.18.1 in one of my SPFX Library projects. I have deployed the library's distribution files to our CDN.
However, when I try to consume this library in my Web Part project and add a component from the library to my .tsx file, it doesn't work and throws the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
'EnvironmentType')

I added tsx from library into my webpart tsx.

Look at Git Issue https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/3075
